# setting picture in image UI element using file picker

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, microsoft-metro, filepicker

In my app user can set profile pic from device memory i.e tablet memory or desktop local drive and upload it to server.
I used file picker so that user can select one picture and set it as profile picture, but the problem is the picture is not sticking to Image element.
My code:

```
 private async void filePicker()
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {

                String filePath = file.Path;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePath);

                Uri uri = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative);
                profilePicture.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
            }
        }

        internal bool EnsureUnsnapped()
        {
            // FilePicker APIs will not work if the application is in a snapped state.
            // If an app wants to show a FilePicker while snapped, it must attempt to unsnap first
            bool unsnapped = ((ApplicationView.Value != ApplicationViewState.Snapped) || ApplicationView.TryUnsnap());
            if (!unsnapped)
            {
                //NotifyUser("Cannot unsnap the sample.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }

            return unsnapped;
        }
```

the file path that I'm getting is this one

```
filePath=C:\Users\Prateek\Pictures\IMG_0137.JPG
```

I don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will solve the problem, this is what I did to set my image source.

Using a bitmap image as the source to your image

```
BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
await bitmapimage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
profilePicture.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code ...

```
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            this.textBlock.Text = 
                "File Path: " + file.Path + Environment.NewLine + 
                "File Name: " + file.Name;

            try
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                await imageSource.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                this.image.Source = imageSource;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.textBlock.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
```